# Finding subclasses of a class in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the Apple docs there are a lot of classes that are meant to be subclassed or abstract classes. How can i find which classes are subclass of a given class?

For instance: If i'm looking at UIDummyClassAbstract, how can i find all classes that are subclassing UIDummyClassAbstract?

It would help to get a better overview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not exactly in Documentation but you can inspect class hierarchy this way:

1. Open "Symbol Navigator" (look for [image] icon)
2. Toggle "Show only project defined symbols" option off ([image] icon in the bottom at the window)
3. You can inspect class tree now :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a free product, if you were to use AppCode instead of Xcode, this stuff is relatively easy, even for classes that you don't own (like in your example).

**Search for Usages**

[image]